# allow editing in uitableview, but not in one row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with multiple sections. When I set the table into edit mode, then I would prefer that one section (which only includes 1 row) does not display the edit symbol and not call  tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:.

Is this possible?

regards
John

Answer (score 8):

here i assume for section 1 and row 0 which can not edit

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            return NO;  
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```